# How to install the latest wkhtmltopdf on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, wkhtmltopdf

I did `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` on my mac and it installed `12.2.1` and works well. I've now deployed to the ubuntu server, and require `wkhtmltopdf` on that server. `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` only installed `0.9`. I followed this [explination](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556667/how-to-install-wkhtmltopdf-0-12-1-on-ubuntu-server) and it kind of worked, I now have `12.1` installed. But it is not behaving the same as version `12.2.1` on my mac.

And when I do `apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` again on the ubuntu server it says the latest version is already installed, even though it's only `12.1`.

How do I get version `12.2.1` onto the ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purge the added PPAs:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:<user/ppa_name>
```

And use [the official packages](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html).

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but what would the user/ppa_name be in this case? I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Depends which ppa you used, `ecometrica/servers` or `pov/wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I did what you said, and used pov/wkhtmltopdf. It installed version 0.9.9.

Comment: Then run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:pov/wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: Thats what I did and it installed wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 and not the latest version.

Comment: You didn't read my answer fully. After purging the ppa, download and install the official `wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-...deb` package for your Ubuntu version from http://wkhtmltopdf.org.

Comment: Sorry, that was really stupid of me. If you you still want to help me, even with my previous stupidity. I'm getting dependency errors when trying to install 
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:i386:
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-base.
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on xfonts-75dpi.
 wkhtmltox:i386 depends on libstdc++6.` 

I've tried all these suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/336795/ubuntu-fix-dependency-problems) and still has the same errors.

Comment: What Ubuntu version you have?

Comment: Thanks so much man, your question was enough to get me to sort it out. I was trying to install the 32bit version on a 64bit Ubuntu. I'm used to Windows where 32bit works on both so didn't even think of that.